# How to plug holes in an Image (with partial convolutions)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

NVIDIA recently published a new way to reconstruct images with holes. They use a new type of convolutional layer which is described in the paper [Image Inpainting for Irregular Holes Using
Partial Convolutions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07723.pdf).

[image]

I'm trying to implement this in Mathematica. The crucial part is the Partial Convolutional Layer (described in section 3.1 on page 5) defined as follows:

[image]

**What I've tried so far:**

```
partialConv = NetInitialize @ NetGraph[
    <|
       "c1" -> ConvolutionLayer[10, {3, 3}, "Weights" -> NetSharedArray["c"]],
       "c2" -> ConvolutionLayer[10, {3, 3}, "Weights" -> NetSharedArray["c"]],
       "thread" -> ThreadingLayer[#1/#2 &]
    |>,
    { 
      NetPort["mask"] -> "c1", 
      NetPort["maskedImg"] -> "c2", 
      {"c1", "c2"} -> "thread" -> NetPort["Output"]
    }, 
      "maskedImg" -> NetEncoder["Image"], 
      "mask" -> NetEncoder["Image"], 
      "Output" -> NetDecoder["Image"]
   ]

img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 70];
mask = Binarize@RemoveBackground@img;
maskedImg = ImageSubtract[img, ColorNegate@mask];
Grid@{{img, maskedImg}}
partialConv[<|"mask" -> mask, "maskedImg" -> img|>]
```

[image]

Comment: Hard to say. What have *you* tried?

Comment: I just skimmed the paper - wouldn't you get the same result if you applied the same convolution filter (with shared weights) to the input image and the mask, both with masked pixels set to 0, then used a ThreadingLayer to divide the two results?

Comment: I think you might be right, trying it now...

Comment: @NikiEstner I'm trying to match things up with the paper using your idea for implementing the partialConv layer, but I'm not sure if it is right